# Error in ReactJS 0.12.2 documentation?

Tags: reactjs

The new ReactJS documentation states that a `ReactComponentElement` includes

```
type ReactComponentElement<TProps> = {
    type : ReactClass<TProps>,
    props : TProps,
    key : string | boolean | number | null,
    ref : string | null
};
```

but when I look at the return of `createElement` I don't see `props` but rather `_store.props`. Is this a documentation error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not an error:

[image]

The `props` property is an important part of an element's API.

Comment: Apparently is a problem in Firebug; if I `console.dir` the element I can see everything.